# Google+ moment posting .NET API 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, android, .net, rest, google-plus

We have a problem with the insert moment method in the Google+ REST API service.

Our use case is the following: our Android application get an offline authorization code from the GoogleAuthUtil with the following class:

```
public class GetGooglePlusToken extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private GoogleApiClient apiClient;

    public GetGooglePlusToken(Context context, GoogleApiClient apiClient)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String serverClientId = "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" // Client ID for web application from google developer console
        String scopesString = Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME;
        String scope = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + serverClientId + ":api_scope:" + scopesString;
        Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
        appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
        String code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        context,                                     
                        Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(apiClient),  
                        scope,                                       
                        appActivities                                 
                    );

        return code;
    }
}
```

We send the authorization code to an asp.net webapi server. The authorization code will be replaced to an access token by the server. With this access token we try to post something to the user's wall with the following code, but we always get 401 unauthorized http error:

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
    {
        ClientId = "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" // ClientID for web application from google developer console
        ClientSecret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyy" // Client Secret from google developer console
    },
    Scopes = new string[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin, PlusService.Scope.PlusMe },
});

var tokenResponse = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("", authorizationCode, "", CancellationToken.None).Result;

var credential = new UserCredential(flow, "me", tokenResponse);

var body = new Moment();
var itemScope = new ItemScope();

itemScope.Id = "customid01";
itemScope.Type = "";
itemScope.Description = "The description for the action";
itemScope.Name = "An example of add activity";

body.Object = itemScope;
body.Type = " http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

var plusService1 = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleKeyForBrowserApps"], // Key for browser applications from developer console
});

// ok
var me1 = plusService1.People.Get("me").Execute();

var insert1 = new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(plusService1, body, "me", MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault);
// 401 error
Moment wrote1 = insert1.Execute();
```

On the Google+ developer site the insert moment developer console notes that currently the developer console is not able to post:https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert. See the bottom of the page: IMPORTANT! The APIs Explorer below does not currently work. It returns a "401 Unauthorized" error. It is only valid for the developer console, however we get the same error.

Do you have any idea how can we solve this issue? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Moments describe activities that users engage within your app.  Yet you say you are trying to post to a users wall.   It is not possible to post to a users wall using the Google+ API.  What exactly are you doing?

Comment: It is clear that posting is not allowed with Google+ API. However inserting moments in the name of an application is supported by the Google+ REST API (see example above).